Find all the values $x\in\mathbb{R}$ where the Series converge
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}+3n}{2^{n}+5n}(x-1)^{n}
$$
I calculate the limit $n\to\infty$ with the D'Alambert ratio test, and the series converges in the interval $-1<x<3$:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}+3n}{2^{n}+5n}(x-1)^{n}\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}
$$
Then calc the convergence in $x=-1$ and $x=3$ and series converge in the interval extremes, and in $x=-1$ converges absolutely and conditionally(by Leibniz Alternating series test, I prove to decrease by derivate of the $a_{n}$) and in $x=3$ converges.
Is my procedure OK?
So Series converges in $[-1, 3]$

Diverges at the boundries.

Missing an "$(x-1)$" on the right-hand side of the second display.

Hint: Apply general term test at the boundries.

At the boundaries, the absolute value of the $n$-th term if the series becomes
$$\frac{\sqrt{n} + 3n}{2^n +5n}2^n=\frac{\sqrt{n} +3n}{1+2^{-n}5n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty
$$
Thus the series diverges at the endpoints.
